# How to parse multidimensional array in string format back to multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, angular, parsing, multidimensional-array

I am using angular5.I have a  `questionOrderList` which is a string which contains multidimensional array in string format. What I need to do is to parse the array in string format back to multidimensional array type. Currently I have used the JSON.parse method my code looks like.

```
    console.log("qorder service : "+questionOrderList)
    console.log("qorder service parsed:" +JSON.parse(questionOrderList))
```

The output I am getting is

```
qorder service : [[3290],[3287],[3289,3293],[3295]]
qorder service parsed: 3290,3287,3289,3293,3295
```

But in case of array with one row it is correct

```
qorder service : [[3290,3287,3289,3293,3295]]
qorder service parsed: 3290,3287,3289,3293,3295
```

Comment: The first output is also correct. That's just the way how JavaScript converts those arrays to a string. Try `console.log(JSON.parse(questionOrderList))` without the string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

What you are going is correct, see this:

```js
var questionOrderList = "[[3290],[3287],[3289,3293],[3295]]";
var parsedList = JSON.parse(questionOrderList);

console.log(parsedList)
```

The actual issue is how JS interprets string concatination with arrays. It implicitly calls `.join(',')` on the array as demonstrated here:

```js
var questionOrderList = "[[3290],[3287],[3289,3293],[3295]]";
var parsedList = JSON.parse(questionOrderList);
console.log(parsedList);
console.log("" + parsedList);
console.log(parsedList.join(','))
```

Comment: But when I run `questionOrderList.length()`  it is giving `1 ` instead of `4`

Comment: please update the queston to show what you're saying